# Add placeholder for marginnote

Tags: tufte-book

I want to add a long note in line with the beginning of the paragraph. Is there a way of adding a placeholder (like `\footnotemark`) for the `\marginnote` to make the text more readable?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 0):

Place the (actual or dummy) margin note before (technically, at) the start of the paragraph.

---

The margin note code can start the paragraph and will be positioned next to the first line in the output when typeset.

Because a line end converts to a space, extra clarity can be added by ending the margin note code on one line and starting the paragraph text on the immediate next line. Be  careful not to insert a blank line, though. A blank line means a new paragraph.

To read a paragraph without code clutter when there are, for example, two or more margin notes in the paragraph, use `\newcommand` to define a macro for each code chunk, to hold the code, give the macro an available short(ish) name and use the macro as an alias for the code: `\newcommand{\xyz}{... really long text ...}`. See the second use of the `\ph` macro in the example code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand\mymn[1]{\marginnote{#1}}
\newcommand\longtext{y y y y q a z w s x e d c v f rr t g b} 
\newcommand\ph{\mymn{\longtext}}
\begin{document}

\ph
x x x x x x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x xx x x
x x x x x x x  x xx x x xx x   x x  xx
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x xx x x


x x x x x x x x x x x x x xx x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  x ss s sßß x
x x x x x xx x x xx xxx x x x x x x x xx s
x xx x x x x x x x x x x x xx x xxx xx x xd
x x \ph  x xx x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x   x x x x x x x  x x x x x   xx   x x x x x x  xx  x
x x x x x x x   x x x x x x x  x x x x x   xx   x x x x x x
x x x x x x x   x x x x x x x  x x x x x   xx   x x x x x x  xx  x


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! What does this do exactly? You don't seem to use the macros you define.

Comment: @cfr Long line; I've made it two lines. Thanks! I was wondering what was going on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).